# how would I filter through divs and detach

Tags: jquery

How would I filter through a list of child divs and detach divs based on a specific index value.

So for example I want to be able to decide what index's I want to detach. for example lets say I have 10 child divs inside a element called holder. I want to be able to filter through them and remove lest say this sequence 
[0, 3, 5, 7]

The above sequence could change. When I filter through the divs I want to be able to detach them and later add them back again using jquery.

I looked into the filter method but not sure how to only filter the element indexes I want. Anyone got any good ideas.

```
<div id="holder">
 <div>1</div>
 <div>2</div>
 <div>3</div>
 <div>4</div>
 <div>5</div>
 <div>6</div>
 <div>7</div>
 <div>8</div>
 <div>9</div>
 <div>10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: meaning jquery .detach()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution if you want to rely on the text inside the div:

```
$('#holder div').each(function(){
    var filter = ['0', '3', '5', '7'];

    if($.inArray($(this).text(), filter) > -1)
    {
        $(this).detach();
    }
});
```

and another solution if you want to rely on the indexes:

```
$('#holder div').each(function(i){
    var filter = [0, 3, 5, 7];

    if($.inArray(i, filter) > -1)
    {
        $(this).detach();
    }
});
```

Comment: Why put `var filter` inside of the loop?

Comment: @bricker Its placement is illustrative.

Comment: How would I attach them back in their same order.

Comment: @Chapsterj you could keep an array and push the elements in it, however, if order is important to you, you should simply use .hide() and .show(). Alternatively, you could simply append the items and use a plugin that can sort dom elements.

Comment: I guess I could use hide and show. I'll try that thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0):

Try the `n-th child` selector

http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you could do this... given that order etc. can change.

```
var a = $('#holder div:eq(0), #holder div:eq(3), #holder div:eq(5)').detach();

$('#holder').append(a[0], a[1], a[2]);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wHbVq/

Comment: This would work but it doesn't allow for the numbers to change. I want to be able to have one number in the sequence or 10 or in between. The numbers could be random. I was hoping to be able to maybe pass in an array of numbers and I could filter the divs based on the array of numbers.

Comment: Correct Chapsterj.  I was just writing a function to go along with this, but @Ingenu beat me to it.  Use his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of using [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/). You only have to return `truthy` values for the index to be retained, which means that you want to keep only the elements that should be detached.

```
$('#holder div').filter(function(i){
  var filter = ['0', '3', '5', '7'];
  return $.inArray($(this).text(), filter) > -1);
}).detach();
```

Alternatively, you can just use selectors for index based filtering:

```
$('#holder div').filter(':eq(0), :eq(3), :eq(5), :eq(7)').detach();
```

For linear filtering, you should use [`:nth-child()`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

```
$('#holder div').filter(':nth-child(2n+3)').detach() //indices 3, 5, 7, 9, etc
```